# <sqlite3.Row object at 0x1017fe3f0> instead of database contents

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

My templates is this:

```
  {% for order in orders %}
    <li><h2>{{ order}}</h2>
  {% endfor %}
```

and my routing function is this:

```
@app.route('/order_history')
def orderhistory():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select * from order_items')
    orders = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('order_history.html', orders = orders)
```

Any idea why I am getting row object locations instead of the db contents?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to get the data *from* the rows:

```
{% for order in orders %}
  <li><h2>{{ order[0] }}</h2></li>
{% endfor %}
```

A SQL query always returns data in rows, containing columns. The above assumes your `SELECT` returned just one column per row.

If you have multiple columns, you'd have to either address these with direct indices (`order[1]`, `order[3]`, etc.) or loop over the row to show the columns:

```
{% for order in orders %}
  <li><h2>{{ order[0] }}</h2>
      {% for column in order %}
          {% if not loop.first %}{{ column }}<br />{% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: is there another option for using direct indices besides this: `<li><h2>{{ order[0], order[1], order[2] }}</h2>`?  THe reason I ask is because it is giving me a weird output: `(1, u'JKL', u'Chilli Peppers')`

Comment: You are using a tuple there. Use separate interpolations, `{{ order[0] }} {{order[1] }}` etc.